# Парсинг с вводом в форму

Tags: веб-скрейпинг

Здравствуйте! Имеется подобный сайт с калькулятором доставки: https://www.correosexpress.com/web/correosexpress/calcula-tu-envio

Мне нужно взять с этого сайта данные после обработки (т.е. ввода) данных. Это вообще возможно через средства PHP, CURL'a или каких нибудь библиотек?

Answer (score 0):

Чисто теоретически - данные подгружаются JavaScript'ом, т.е. откуда-то он их берёт. Как вариант - смоделировать такой-же AJAX-запрос к тому-же ресурсу, к какому обращается сам сайт, подменив передаваемые данные на нужные Вам. Это если "в лоб" решать задачу

Comment: А если не в лоб? :)